# Stateful Transformation on a single Dataframe in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to determine the completion status, at various levels of granularity. For ex, a region is 'complete' if all towns in the region are complete.

I maintain the state at the lowest level(town), in-memory using following approach in Spark:

Step 1. Load initial state from Cassandra table into a Spark Data-frame.

```
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| country  | region |  town  | isComplete |
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| Country1 | State1 | Town1  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town2  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town3  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town4  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town5  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town6  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town7  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town8  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town9  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town10 | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town11 | FALSE      |
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Step 2. Start Stream processing and using the data-frames created in each micro-batch try to update the state in the data-frame from Step1 using Left Outer Join.

Batch1:

```
+----------+--------+-------+------------+
| country  | region | town  | isComplete |
+----------+--------+-------+------------+
| Country1 | State1 | Town1 | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town2 | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town3 | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town4 | TRUE       |
+----------+--------+-------+------------+
```

After applying Batch 1 :

```
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| country  | state  |  town  | isComplete |
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| Country1 | State1 | Town1  | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town2  | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town3  | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town4  | TRUE       |
| Country1 | State1 | Town5  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town6  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town7  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town8  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town9  | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town10 | FALSE      |
| Country1 | State1 | Town11 | FALSE      |
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

My idea is that by keeping the data-frame mutable, I would be able to update it in each batch and maintain the state overall(like a global variable) through out the lifetime of the streaming job.

The base dataset is around 1.2million records(100 MB approx) and is expected to scale up to 10 GB.

I am running into Out of Memory issues. Each batch takes considerably more processing time than the previous batch.  Also the number of stages for same job increases across batches. Ultimately application fails with GC overhead limit exceeded.

```
var statusDf = loadStatusFromCassandra(sparkSession)
ipStream.foreachRDD { statusMsgRDD =>
  if (!statusMsgRDD.isEmpty) {
    // 1. Create data-frame from the current micro-batch RDD
    val messageDf = getMessageDf(sparkSession, statusMsgRDD)

    // 2. To update, Left outer join statusDf with messageDf
    statusDf = updateStatusDf(sparkSession, statusDf, messageDf)

    // 3. Use updated statusDf to generate aggregations at higher levels
    // and publish to a Kafka topic
    // if a higher level (eg. region) is completed.
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you find out the answer?

Comment: No, I haven't. I have not looked around much to be fair. We went back to executing stateless and persisting results after processing every micro-batch into Cassandra.